# Capistrano: linked file database.yml does not exist on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant, capistrano

I am deploying to a local VM. Here is the error:

```
ERROR linked file /var/www/rails-devise-capistrano/shared/config/database.yml does not exist on localhost
```

However, the file does exist:

```
vagrant@vagrant:/var/www/rails-devise-capistrano/shared/config$ ls
database.yml  secrets.yml
```

Any idea how to fix this error?

UPDATE:

```
INFO [81d54d10] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /var/www/rails-devise-capistrano/shared/config /var/www/rails-devise-capistrano/shared/config as vagrant@localhost
DEBUG [81d54d10] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.2.2 /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /var/www/rails-devise-capistrano/shared/config /var/www/rails-devise-capistrano/shared/config )
INFO [81d54d10] Finished in 0.042 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [44d62e62] Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /var/www/rails-devise-capistrano/shared/config/database.yml ] as vagrant@localhost
DEBUG [44d62e62] Command: [ -f /var/www/rails-devise-capistrano/shared/config/database.yml ]
DEBUG [44d62e62] Finished in 0.042 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
```

Comment: Can you post the last few lines of the capistrano log output leading up to the error? In particular I am looking for lines like `DEBUG ... Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /var/www ...`.

Comment: Thanks @MattBrictson, please see my update above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capistrano uses command `[ -f PATH ]` to test that `database.yml` exists. It is getting back a non-zero exit status from that test, which is why it gives you an error.

According to the bash man page:

> -f file True if file exists and is a regular file.

Is it possible that your `database.yml` is a directory? Or is otherwise not "a regular file"? Or maybe the `vagrant` user does not have permission to access it?

Comment: vagrant@vagrant: stat /var/www/rails-devise-capistrano/shared/config/deploy.yml revealed that the file was indeed a directory. Thanks!